# datagridview not displaying currency format

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Firstly I used the following to populate the `DataGridView`:

```
        dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" & ActName & "$B6:E" & LastEntryRow & "]", cn)
        dts = New DataSet
        dta.Fill(dts, "Detailtable")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "Detailtable"
```

I then formatted the DataGridView which included the following code:

```
    Dim currencyCellStyle As New DataGridViewCellStyle
    currencyCellStyle.Format = "C2"

    With Me.DataGridView
        .Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle = currencyCellStyle
        .Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle = currencyCellStyle
    End with
```

This worked well. Columns displayed their values as $1234.00.
When new values were added to the columns they immediately displayed as $1234.00. (working so far)

If a column did not have any values when the dataset was made, no values showed in the datagridview for that column. (no problem so far)

However, all new values added to the blank column display as 1234.00. Not $1234.00.

I have tried refreshing the DataGridView
I have re-formatted the DataGridView after the change to the cell.
It still displays as 1234.00.

If I save the changes, recreate the DataSet and repopulate the DataGridView all is OK.

I need the DataGridView to reflect the correct format ($1234.00) when new values are added directly to the column?????

Comment: If you place the line: Me.DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2" immediately after you bind and the column is numeric, it works. See:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f9x2790s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-5

Comment: I have added the following immediately after binding the binding:             DataGridView1.Columns(1).ValueType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
            DataGridView1.Columns(2).ValueType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
            DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2"
            DataGridView1.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2".  Howver when adding values to the blank column still shows values as 1234.00 rather than $1234.00.

Comment: This is probably because the column type in the datatable is not numeric. Check the datacolumn data type.

Answer (score 3):

If you use this line

```
DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C2"
```

it must be work but if your **database column format is not Decimal** (but TEXT), this type of format it'll never works.